# TemplateSyntaxError at /cart/, Invalid block tag: '"cart:cart_remove"', expected 'endwith'

Tags: python, django

I'm doing the webshop following the code in the book "Django by Example". I tried Google and searches in Stackoverflow but I did not find answers to this problem.

The product list page and the product detail page work fine but when I try to add items to the cart, the browser says: 
TemplateSyntaxError at /cart/, Invalid block tag: '"cart:cart_remove"', expected 'endwith'.

Here is a screenshot of a part of the error page:
[error page code lines, maybe the picture is more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHJC.png). Here you can also see the code of the error page:

```
23                  {% with product=item.product %}
24                      <tr>
25                          <td>
26                              <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
27                                  <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url
28                                  }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
29                              </a>
30                          </td>
31                          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
32                          <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
33  
                              <td><a href="
      {% "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}
      ">Remove</a></td>


34                          <td class="num">${{ item.price }}</td>
35                          <td class="num">${{ item.total_price }}</td>
36                      </tr>
37                  {% endwith %}
```

I checked the code. As you can see below, I have the endwith tag so I don't understand why it gives me that kind of an error. Pycharm was complaining about the " so I changed it to ' for the  'no_image.png' and 'cart:cart_remove'. However, I tried to run the website after replacing ' with ", but it gives me the same error.

Maybe this problem is related. Pycharm is complaining about the shop models at cart\view.py and underlines it with red:

```
from shop.models import Product
```

Pycharm says Unresolved reference 'shop'.

Also the shop\view.py has a similar problem with this:

```
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
```

I had some similar unresolved reference problem earlier but it seemed to have disappeared by itself somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `endwith`, but with the tag that is highlighted. `"cart:cart_remove"` is not a tag; I expect you meant to use `{% url "cart:cart_remove" ... %}` there.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! Somehow I forgot to add the "url" in there. I tried to check that I had the same code as the book, but I guess I should have triple-checked. I was focusing on the endwith thing and wondering if the other problems are affecting the whole thing.